# Error fetching data from axios in vuejs app

Tags: javascript, api, vue.js, axios

Hey I am trying to make a full stack app with vuejs fastifyjs(node framework). The vue app gets data from the api I developed and also display it in the browser console but it does not render it in the app. I even tried to load it on mount function but nothing happens.

Here is the complete code I am using.

```js
const app = new Vue({
  el:'#app',

  data:{
    infos: [{
      name: 'Vue',
      age: 19,
      imageUrl: 's3.aws.amazon.com'
    }, {
      name: 'Vue 2',
      age: 20,
      imageUrl: 's3.aws.amazon.com2'
    }],
    msg: 'Hello Vuejs!'
  },

  methods:{
    getData: function(){
      axios.get('http://localhost:3000/getData')
        .then(function(result){
          this.infos = result.data
          console.log(infos)
        })
        .catch(function(err){
          console.log(err)
        })
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<div id="app">
  {{msg}}
  <button v-on:click="getData">Get Data</button><br><br>
  <div v-for="info in infos">
    <br>
    <span>Name: {{info.name}}</span><br>
    <span>Age: {{info.age}}</span><br>
    <span>Image: {{info.imageUrl}}</span><br>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue"></script>
<script src="index.js"></script>
```

Here is the image of what I am getting.

[The default values get rendered and also at the right the array gets logged.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cxl3S.png)

The complete code is here
https://github.com/siddiquiehtesham/fullstack-vue-nodejs-api

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your axios request, `this` is not bound to your Vue instance.

Use arrow function instead to keep the right context:

```
getData: function() {
  axios.get('http://localhost:3000/getData')
  .then(result => {
    this.infos = result.data
    console.log(this.infos)
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log(err)
  })
}
```

or set a `self` variable before the request:

```
getData: function() {
  let self = this
  axios.get('http://localhost:3000/getData')
  .then(function(result) {
    self.infos = result.data
    console.log(self.infos)
  })
  .catch(function(err) {
    console.log(err)
  })
}
```

Comment: Hey that worked ! Thank you. I have a doubt that why do I have to use arrow function instead of normal function? And I was using function keyword because when I was writing everything in arrow functions the getData: was not working but when I wrote function it worked. What's the concept which I am missing or I don't know?

Comment: If you want to know more about `this` keyword and its using context here's [a good post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20279485/9541423) explaining why and how.